# Probability of two ordered discrete random variables

Tags: probability

I'm not sure for this problem I should assume independence and then use the product of the pmf.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be nonnegative integer-values random variables. Show that $P(X \le{Y})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n \sum_{k=0}^n q_k$ where $p_n=P(Y=n)$ and $q_K =P(X=n)$

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Try simply.  Suppose y=1.  What can x be?  What’s that probability?  Now suppose y=2.  What can x be?  What is the probability of each of those outcomes?  Proceed.

Comment: @NicNic8 Thanks for the que. If y=1, the x=0 or 1. If y=2, then x=0,1,2.  And because these r.v. are discrete, the probability of each is a cumulative sum. Is my reasoning on track?